# Share file between Android Wear and mobile

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, wear-os

I'm triyng to share a file between a wear and a mobile.
I would like to know what is the best practice with an example.

1. Using SharedPreferences ?
2. Using a common library as dependancy which contain the file ?
3. The file is in the mobile project and the wear access it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the (The Wearable Data Layer API) http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html.

> The API consists of a set of data objects that the system can send and synchronize over the wire and listeners that notify your apps of important events with the data layer

Answer (score 1):

Our answer is (2) - we typically create a common library (aka module in Android Studio) to share between our mobile and wear apps.

Please take a look at our SynchronizedNotifications sample under samples/android-20/wearable/. You will see a module called Common which contains the class Constants. This in turn contains all the URIs that we use to key off DataItems.